# Lights in Three.js not affecting meshes added to the scene after the light

Tags: webgl, three.js

Basically when I add a light to a scene, I need to wait ~100ms to add meshes or else the dynamic lighting will not be applied to the mesh.  In my current implementation, I replace all of the relevant parts whenever a new light is added, although this seems inefficient and wrong.  Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Does the Materials section in the [Wiki article](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) help you?

Comment: Somewhat.  Setting the material.needsUpdate to true didn't really help.  Is there anything more specific that I would need to do?

Comment: Did you read about "dummy" lights and why to use them?

Comment: Yes, although I don't believe that it is possible to use them in my scenario.  Lights are dynamically created based on user input.

Comment: That is a perfect case for using them. I'd suggest you try. If it doesn't work, then you will have to provide sufficient information for someone to help you.